# renderPartial in CGridView cell

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I want to render a php view file in the cell of a CGridView.

Therefore I wrote this code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'columns'=>array(
      array(
          'value'=>array($this, 'renderPartial("_lineProblems")')
      ))));
```

But I get this error:

`BookController and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "renderPartial('_lineProblems' )".`

The stack trace shows this as the problem:

```
call_user_func_array(array(BookController, "renderPartial('_lineProblems' )"), array("data" => line, "row" => 0, 0 => CDataColumn))
```

I don't understand the error. $this is an instance of BookController and BookController is a child of CController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution with the help of another [Yii programmer](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/35276-renderpartial-in-cgridview-cell/)

```
$controller = $this;

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'columns'=>array(
      array(
          'name'=>'errors',
          'value'=>function($data, $row) use ($controller){
                return $controller->renderPartial('_lineProblems', array('errors'=>$data->errors), true);
          }
      )
  ),
));
```